# CFBundleUrlTypes visible in the Info.plist but not in the XCode view of it

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I am debugging my integration of Facebook iOS SDK 4.10 on iOS 9 (it works but the login is always done through a webview and doesn't open the Facebook app).

I have a problem with `CFBundleUrlTypes`, I have added it (many times) through XCode: `Project > Info > Url Types`... In fact it is persisted, because I can: `cat Info.plist|grep -C 10 -i urltypes` and get:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb$(FACEBOOK_APP_ID)</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

But I relaunch XCode it's not visible anymore in the project info.

[image: XCode Project Info]

Answer (score 0):

Starting from iOS9, Facebook uses the Safari View Controller for Login rather than a fast app switch. The SDK basically tries to determine the best possible experience for the user so this is probably why you are always routed to the web based login.

It is also partly to get around the "APPNAME wants to open OTHERAPP" you will see in iOS9.

The documentation slightly touches on this here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9#faq

Comment: So you basically mean this is normal and I shouldn't try to do anything against this?